# Rendering HTML within classes?

Tags: php, html, class

Here's the scenario; Within the admin section of a website I have quite a few CRUD tables, which needs success/info/error messages to be displayed when an action has been performed such as a record being deleted. I'm sure everyone is familiar with this.

This usually involves the messages being wrapped within `<div class="alert alert-success">User updated</div>` or something similar.

In the current Laravel application I am creating, I have a configuration file:

```
<?php

return array(

    'info'    => array(

        'start'   => '<div class="callout callout-info"><h3><i class="icon-info-sign-sign"></i> Information</h3>',
        'opening' => '<i class="icon-caret-right"></i> ',
        'closing' => '<br>',
        'end'     => '</div>',

    ),

    'success' => array(

        'start'   => '<div class="callout callout-success"><h3><i class="icon-ok-sign"></i> Success</h3>',
        'opening' => '<i class="icon-caret-right"></i> ',
        'closing' => '<br>',
        'end'     => '</div>',

    ),

    'warning' => array(

        'start'   => '<div class="callout callout-warning"><h3><i class="icon-warning-sign"></i> Warning</h3>',
        'opening' => '<i class="icon-caret-right"></i> ',
        'closing' => '<br>',
        'end'     => '</div>',

    ),

    'error'   => array(

        'start'   => '<div class="callout callout-danger"><h3><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i> Warning</h3>',
        'opening' => '<i class="icon-caret-right"></i> ',
        'closing' => '<br>',
        'end'     => '</div>',

    )

);
```

Which a formatter class uses to render an object of `MessageBag` (stores an array eg. validation errors such as invalid email) into the readable HTML. This isn't exactly storing HTML within the Formatter class, but it does render within it.

The formatter class simply renders a MessageBag object with a configuration option so:

```
$formatter = new Formatter('success', $messageBag);
$html = $formatter->render();
```

Which is then passed from the controller to the view and displayed.

```
return View::make('admin.template')->with('message', $html);
```

This method allows me to update the HTML and how it renders across the whole admin section from within one class. Thus going along with the `DRY` principle. It reduces all the `foreach` loops across my templates.

So this begs the question...

**Is it better to repeat yourself within the view templates rather than mix up business and presentation layers? Or vice versa?**

*My personal opinion (currently) is that using a configuration file in conjunction with the class is a good solution. I do also think storing HTML within a class is bad practice, hence the config file.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really a judgement call.

Most of the time I prefer keeping HTML out of classes and configuration files. Instead, I put as much of the HTML as possible in templates. Templates shared by different views can be stored in a shared location and parsed by the templating engine in the correct context.

By the way, I make huge exceptions to this concept when writing small applications and extensions. Although I think both are important, I guess I value pragmatic thinking over being consistent.

The real questions are, how much time will it take to separate all your different data types and will the reward for doing so be big enough to justify the time and effort you will have put into it?